# What is DetailsView.EnableModelValidation?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, detailsview

The [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview.enablemodelvalidation.aspx) documentation on DetailsView.EnableModelValidation is very brief:

> Gets or sets a value that indicates whether data-model validation is enabled.

Figuring out that `true` means enabled and `false` means disabled is simple, I could have found out even without the documentation.

What *functionality* is enabled with this setting and how is it used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidebb/archive/2008/06/18/using-asp-net-dynamic-data-with-objectdatasource.aspx

Check out this link, it is for validating the properties on an `ObjectDataSource` when decorating with `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`

Comment: The link was invalid.